# HAML loop through has_and_belongs_to_many objects instead of ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

```
class Team
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  field :name,              :type => String, :default => "My New Team"
  validates_presence_of :name
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users

end
```

In my show.haml for Team, I'm trying:

```
 - @team[:users].each do |user|
        %tr
          %td= link_to user.name, user
          %td= user.email
```

But the problem is that Mongo is storing the users reference as user_ids. So

- @team[:user_ids].each do |user|

But now I'll have to execute a query for each user... Before I do so I just wanted to know if there is another way to loop through the users? I was thinking of putting a variable in the controller called @user_objects but not sure how to generate that without looping through all the user_ids and doing a find() call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
- @team.users.each do |user|
    %tr
      %td= link_to user.name, user
      %td= user.email
```

it will work absolutely fine.